# DNS server can't resolve localhost name

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, redhat, localhost, resolv.conf

I'm trying to set up an Apache server on my RHEL6.4 vm and can't because `dnsmasq` can't recognize the hostname for some reason:

```
nslookup rhel64.example.com
Server:         xxx.xxx.xx.1
Address:        xxx.xxx.xx.1#53

server can't find rhel64.exmple.com: NXDOMAIN
```

`/etc/hosts`:

```
xxx.x.x.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

`/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
; generated by /sbin/dhclient-script
search novalocal example.com
nameserver xxx.xxx.xx.1
```

Please let me know if there is anything you need to see to solve my problem. I cannot use a different DNS server.

Looking for a way to make `dnsmasq` resolve the hostname without changing DNS servers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would expect IP address for your server to be fixed.  Your `/etc/hosts` should contain

```
127.0.0.1  localhost
127.0.0.1  localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4 
::1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
xxx.x.x.1  rhel64.example.com rhel64
```

`localhost` should never point to an address other than 127.0.0.1 or ::1.  Add additional hosts with fixed addresses to `/etc/hosts` as required.

For dynamic addresses, make sure that you have set the correct domain in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`, and ensure that the hostname is sent in the request.   Check the `dnsmasq.leases` file which should be in the `/var/lib` directory try to verify.  Domain should be specified like this.

```
domain=example.com
```

Alternatively you can provide fixed addresses in the `dnsmasq.conf` file or `/etc/ethers`.   A line like this will map mac address `aa.bb.cc.dd.ee.ff` to `192.0.2.1`.  DNS name would be specified in `/etc/hosts` as noted above.

```
 aa.bb.cc.dd.ee.ff     192.0.2.1
```

EDIT: Diagnostics I would use include.

Running getent on the host with dnsmasq running.

```
 getent hosts rhel64
```

This should return the value you entered in the hosts file or returned by DNS.  If that works try using the `host` command to lookup the address.  Use `nslookup` if hosts is not available.  Try these commands.  (It appears your `dnsmasq` and `apache` servers are on the same host.

```
 hosts rhel64.
 hosts rhel64.example.com.
 hosts rhel64.  localhost
 hosts rhel64.example.com.  localhost
 hosts rhel64.  rhel64. 
 hosts rhel64.example.com.  rhel64.
 hosts rhel64.  rhel64.example.com.
 hosts rhel64.example.com.  rhel64.example.com.
```

Which command fails and how it fails should help you determine the problem.  You may also want to ensure that dnsmasq is listening on all ip addresses.

When diagnosing the problem: Requests for `rhel64.` are for the host name unqualified with a domain, and requests for `rhel64.example.com.` are for fully qualified name.  The final dot on the names tells the resolver not to try domains from the search list.  The second host name if specified overrides the name servers listed in `/etc/resolv.conf`.  In this case, I have used the servers from `/etc/resolv.conf`, the localhost address (127.0.0.1 or ::1), the address of the hostname as looked up from DNS, and address of the fully qualified name as looked up from the name sever. The last two servers won't work if the initial look for the name failed.

```
 netstat -an | grep :53
```

EDIT: On re-reading your post, I notice you are getting your address from DHCP,  the notes on setting a fixed IP address apply to Unix style DHCP servers.  They should be applied to the dchp-server which is likely the  router at xxx.x.x.1, which would not be your servers address.  You should be able to get the curent IP address with either the command `ifconfig` or the newer command `ip addr`.  This is the address which should be matched with your host name in the /etc/hosts file.

If you don't have access to the router, you can try to get DHCP to update the DNS service for you.  Add the following entry to our DHCP configuration file:
    option fqdn.fqdn rhel64.example.com; 
or 
    option fqdn.fqdn rhel64;

After adding the entry you will need to restart the `dhclient` process.  Try the commands

```
sudo dhclient -r
sudo dhclient
```

Otherwise you will need to restart the interface or the entire networking setup.

Comment: I added the host and restarted the httpd and dnsmasq and I still get the error when I do an 'nslookup' on the hostname.

Comment: Server:         xxx.xxx.xx.1
Address:        xxx.xxx.xx.1#53

** server can't find rhel64: SERVFAIL

Comment: Server:         localhost
Address:        ::1#53

Name:   rhel64
Address: 'host machine address'

Comment: Server:         localhost
Address:        ::1#53

Name:   rhel64.example.com
Address: 'host machine name'

Comment: Server:         xxx.xxx.xx.1
Address:        xxx.xxx.xx.1#53

** server can't find rhel64.example.com: NXDOMAIN

Comment: nslookup: couldn't get address for 'rhel64.': not found

Comment: nslookup: couldn't get address for 'rhel64.': not found

Comment: These are the results from each of the commands listed using 'nslookup' since 'hosts' was not available. Obviously if i knew what they meant I could fix identify the problem but that is not the case.

Comment: I have updated with more information.  It looks like you server is not registering its name with the DHCP server.